# Amazon EC2 - HTTPS - Certificate body is invalid. The body must not contain a private key

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl

I'm very new to Amazon EC2. I am trying to setup https for my website, I follow the offical instruction from amazon doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

When I Upload a Signed Certificate using AWS command

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name dichcumga --certificate-body file://mycert.pem --private-key file://signedkey.pem --certificate-chain file://mychain.pem
```

And I got error

> A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCert
>   ificate operation: Certificate body is invalid. The body must not contain a private key.

mycert.pem is a combination of private.pem and signedkey.pem (which return by VeriSign)

```
copy private.pem+signedkey.pem mycert.pem
```

Please help to shed a light. Thank you in advance.

### [Update 1 - 08/21/2014]: Issue with public certificate returns from the CA

As suggestion of @mezi, I follow the instruction at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html

But I get the issue with public certificate returns from the CA.

- I submit CSR request
- CA returns me an email with the public certificate as plain text

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwGggDCCBPYwggPeoAMC
>   AQICED0qLOh43VCbqW0sDf5mb+swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgcsxCzAJBgNVBAYT
>   AlVTMRcwFQYDVQQKEw5WZXJpU2lnbiwgSW5jLjEwMC4GA1UECxMnRm9yIFRlc3Qg
>   UHVycG9zZXMgT25seS4gIE5vIGFzc3VyYW5jZXMuMUIwQAYDVQQLEzlUZXJtcyBv
>   ZiB1c2UgYXQgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL2Nwcy90ZXN0Y2EgKGMp
>   MDkxLTArBgNVBAMTJFZlcmlTaWduIFRyaWFsIFNlY3VyZSBTZXJ2ZXIgQ0EgLSBH
>   MjAeFw0xNDA4MjEwMDAwMDBaFw0xNDA5MjAyMzU5NTlaMFwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlZO
>   MRIwEAYDVQQIEwlIb0NoaU1pbmgxEjAQBgNVBAcUCUhvQ2hpTWluaDEQMA4GA1UE
>   ChQHRXBpbmlvbjETMBEGA1UEAxQKZGljaGN1bS5nYTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
>   BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALA9p0sxl7egvc93GUsy9i0ShGBt//9dr+nqudpAfPtP
>   Bq4ZS/xle1YiX3zilOQ4uAduGfKpEQc1/h1Pa/ShUXhwxXvdmdOXTOEBUIHaGKKl
>   wG3pDpFfNGIo5mf+5sPIEEHsakyp6lwBgmESELI6BnV/FuVuxvdW3T4gORXaLJsh
>   xqW/69kO62FVP8pTcj50r4vRk5SkHos5C2zKKcCCdE/OAWyQ7rRW1bSM6SCipWQh
>   1xvYFqKzscAwtMYVbow17p9RWx50J3Jv8U0+je7XzgFD2O2E8bCvpaR5DVGRNbbF
>   pdoUZA0L2liV+/hGVbsDbNxY7gCS/PoJWvsMptQfy9cCAwEAAaOCAUIwggE+MBUG
>   A1UdEQQOMAyCCmRpY2hjdW0uZ2EwCQYDVR0TBAIwADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAw
>   KwYDVR0fBCQwIjAgoB6gHIYaaHR0cDovL3NxLnN5bWNiLmNvbS9zcS5jcmwwZQYD
>   VR0gBF4wXDBaBgpghkgBhvhFAQcVMEwwIwYIKwYBBQUHAgEWF2h0dHBzOi8vZC5z
>   eW1jYi5jb20vY3BzMCUGCCsGAQUFBwICMBkWF2h0dHBzOi8vZC5zeW1jYi5jb20v
>   cnBhMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQo
>   FxOKvdaitdwGLLe2jtoQZmBu5TA2BggrBgEFBQcBAQQqMCgwJgYIKwYBBQUHMAKG
>   Gmh0dHA6Ly9zcS5zeW1jYi5jb20vc3EuY3J0MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQDE
>   UtCDek5Gq0Ilw+WCCD6jz+s35wxlLPvNIeIGaRky2PwnXdrAZV8iwfVmg26Nua9W
>   JNsKlnsdiev854M7ztQv3IjArvS+fBIj5o4T9WKdQP+EUISPI2yTVqa1bu6mDZEw
>   EhwxAGCVT4Na5EjEvD2zc/V5ukFnGK8wFFty4lY/YclOAdFIAILHb/4vOeebdWcJ
>   X2d6+KigvcQuIqOce8MhB48DgpeEBWNZjQMr3D3jLHgs+c9QFEaHkjXFF14Kxo1r
>   D3KaexqdyQJLH26z7hjd58TPeMvx++69m6f/oEKG63pUoF2XfRwaCIVgQohh3I2D
>   PCxcgFJ21zCFBNKHJ3JFMIIFfDCCBGSgAwIBAgIQfju3hLvGVKvSuNZ37MOUqDAN
>   BgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBjDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWdu
>   LCBJbmMuMTAwLgYDVQQLEydGb3IgVGVzdCBQdXJwb3NlcyBPbmx5LiAgTm8gYXNz
>   dXJhbmNlcy4xMjAwBgNVBAMTKVZlcmlTaWduIFRyaWFsIFNlY3VyZSBTZXJ2ZXIg
>   Um9vdCBDQSAtIEcyMB4XDTA5MDQwMTAwMDAwMFoXDTE5MDMzMTIzNTk1OVowgcsx
>   CzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRcwFQYDVQQKEw5WZXJpU2lnbiwgSW5jLjEwMC4GA1UECxMn
>   Rm9yIFRlc3QgUHVycG9zZXMgT25seS4gIE5vIGFzc3VyYW5jZXMuMUIwQAYDVQQL
>   EzlUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2UgYXQgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL2Nwcy90
>   ZXN0Y2EgKGMpMDkxLTArBgNVBAMTJFZlcmlTaWduIFRyaWFsIFNlY3VyZSBTZXJ2
>   ZXIgQ0EgLSBHMjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBANsTzSdP
>   SAMzV5hTV6ImkhXRbCA760I/Fx2ZAY1ZWG+IpM47+QX5TcLW0VoOyXwJtSGOj+Zn
>   Kr9KMmAlb/jcjM9WHzgitJzpSVKylU4dOSH2o9UjAPuq0bZA6xfNV4mzr4rggtE5
>   lGIyQ32AbKjqOjgEKvSVZ/061J7EDz7wRWgHY24xRUQrh4C+2y1boQfAq+s1cp4Y
>   VDxYInIl5aNNxThQvJY7ibkJ6jEH+sNuEdEIK5g6YzwjVPbFAYu00LYusq/WgR18
>   misNumlMfV+tb1hwM70KMMWArVBtFkbkpLIwNpvrhLR/wY8l6tPBHkFQ4Rnwy0nB
>   vzogCNwmWU2f6QUCAwEAAaOCAZcwggGTMDQGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCgwJjAkBggrBgEF
>   BQcwAYYYaHR0cDovL29jc3AudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8C
>   AQAwSwYDVR0gBEQwQjBABgpghkgBhvhFAQcVMDIwMAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWJGh0dHBz
>   Oi8vd3d3LnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS9jcHMvdGVzdGNhLzA7BgNVHR8ENDAyMDCgLqAs
>   hipodHRwOi8vY3JsLnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS9TVlJUcmlhbFJvb3RHMi5jcmwwDgYD
>   VR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMG0GCCsGAQUFBwEMBGEwX6FdoFswWTBXMFUWCWltYWdlL2dp
>   ZjAhMB8wBwYFKw4DAhoEFI/l0xqGrI2Oa8PPgGrUSBgsexkuMCUWI2h0dHA6Ly9s
>   b2dvLnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS92c2xvZ28uZ2lmMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQoFxOKvdaitdwG
>   LLe2jtoQZmBu5TAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRIGeeSb5KdNGOZwPCZyNaljIx/ZTANBgkq
>   hkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEANgvA9cj2h5yFC2SJMmE8a9trUmjnorZWO/Ifmdf5ADuQ
>   uf+k8arodHpdSeq/f2GjwDIo3oYL2bT/66tw46Kx3Q/Z02pp7YW+BRvKejBYXN9F
>   JxsXEkPKpz4SRvSQLl5YBst7q03nK0lZQ4/LE+hufgvx08JdqGd4o4cOvZ6o4MQa
>   MgX/0lwNjC+4PWuKfmrKmr+RhpSkc72cEEO9//XsYesTMetY3nOuqXAQqiH4lz3K
>   AzqNgohXXcF8W1F3ytTTq1yWbMkJonRpXbE3U0rWI33ywiS7LAk8n4dR8tNoqqIr
>   P6sDtvolx9/+qTPWGnYytV0P/hcJt5CbqE7008EnPQAAMQAAAAAAAAA=
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

- Next, I copy the code to notepad and save as **public.pem** file
- Then I use openssl command to check if it is in PEM format or not

> openssl x509 -inform PEM -in **public.pem**

and i get error

> unable to load certificate
>   1952:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:.\crypto\as
>   n1\tasn_dec.c:1319:
>   1952:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:.\
>   crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509_CINF
>   1952:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 e
>   rror:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:751:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
>   1952:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:.\crypto\pem\pem_oth
>   .c:83:

--> this is not in PEM format, do I make a mistake here, please help ?

Comment: Follow this doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html. Make sure the certificates and private key are in PEM format. If not, you will have to convert it. The link explains it all.

Comment: I still get issue with public certificate returns from the CA (verisign.com) - please see update above

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has fixed the problem, as per a comment on an answer, but hasn't specified exactly what they did wrong and how they fixed it. Thus, the question will not be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

That (update 1) file is in PEM format -- assuming the dashes-BEGIN-CERTIFICATE-dashes and dashes-END-CERTIFICATE-dashes are actually on separate lines, which isn't clear from your paste format -- but it is not *a certificate* in PEM format. PEM format is used for many different types of objects. This one is a PKCS7/CMS signed-data with empty data and two certs: one EE cert for Epinion dichcum.ga and one CA (chain) cert for Verisign Trial Secure Server CA G2. This format -- PKCS7 signed-data with empty data and certs -- is a common way to distribute related certs and is usually called "p7b" or "p7c".

Change the word `CERTIFICATE` in the BEGIN and END lines to `PKCS7`. Run `openssl pkcs7 -print_certs <public.pem >tempfile`. The output file `tempfile` will contain *TWO* text blocks each consisting of a BEGIN line, some lines of data, and an END line. Use any text editor or a utility like sed to put these blocks in separate files, let's say `mycert.pem` and `chaincert.pem`. Upload the first file as your cert and the second file as the chain cert, along with your private key file (apparently `private.pem`).

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. Thanks Dave for your suggestion, I already buy the real one and setup successfully. Thanks.